# Window closes when enter is pressed on inputText

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces project which has some inputTexts and 2 buttons, first one gets the result according to given values through inputText and the second cleans the inputTexts. My problem is when I write a value to an inputText area and press enter the window closes itself. It doesn't have to trigger the first button at the moment but It shouldn't close the window either. I couldn't figure out what's wrong. Can someone help?

The code is something like this

```html
<p:inputText id="text1" maxlength="8" value="value">
   <p:keyFilter mask="num" preventPaste="false" />
</p:inputText>
```

Comment: Please answer your question instead of adding solved to the title.

Answer (score 0):

adding the following code block worked for me

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if(keycode == 13){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```